# Cordova-react-android app with hot reload on emulator device

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, reload

Does anyone have success with cordova/react hot reload functionality on an android device at 2021?
All replies I've found either is deprecated/broken or provide live reload on desktop version only, with no access to device features.

I create cordova project merged it with create-react-app and right now I'am able to check the changes on android emulator each time running `cordova run android` only.

Any help will be appreciated.